# Node labels are not in sequence in trees using fancyRpartPlot

Tags: r, machine-learning, decision-tree, rattle

I applied the decision tress algorithm to famous breast cancer data set from UCI after removing 16 records with missing rows. The tree I obtained is given below. As it can be seen that the small number appearing on top of the node are not in order. The numbers are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13, 14, 28 and 20. Are the missing nodes deleted due to pruning? Can I enable the option to see them? Can I correct the sequence according to the nodes appearing i.e. 1 to 13?
[image]